# Deliver high voltage/high frequency sine wave

Tags: ultrasound

I need to deliver a 40 V (minimum), 4.25 MHz, sine wave to a PZT transducer (medical ultrasound application). I have explored trying to use a dc/dc step-up with a switch, but this will only give me a square wave as I understand it. Furthermore, I have tried to search oscillators but most give within the range of 1-3V outputs and as we all know, op-amps can't output more than their supply voltage an I'm trying to stay away from directly supplying 40V to a single element of my circuit. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I feel I have hit a dead end.

Comment: How much power do you require at the output?

Comment: nearly all medical ultrasound imaging uses on/off switches, what's wrong with that?

Comment: And: you want to generate 40V, but you don't want to deal with supplying 40V for your components? I have bad news for you...

Comment: XY problem smell

Comment: "I have explored trying to use a dc/dc step-up with a switch, but this will only give me a square wave as I understand it"  A square wave's fundamental frequency can be filtered to produce a sine wave.

Comment: What's wrong with supplying 40V directly?  opamp->bjt/fet pass element.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat to give you an insight into how ill prepared I am to handle something like this, the answer to your question is I do not know. All I know is that our signal at 10V is currently being attenuated far too much so I need to increase the voltage in an easy/light/cheap way.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold this is a wearable device that I am designing, I have no idea about supply power but I'm guessing the more voltage the bigger the battery? I'd like to keep this as small as possible... could be totally wrong about this though.

Comment: @Norm, that was a possibility I was just looking into today; I just wanted to see if there were other options possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 opamps, the first opamp is inverting, as is the 2nd opamp; first opamp has gain of -10, thus 1vpeak becomes -10 volts peak output; the 2nd opamp exactly (as exact you can get at 4.25MHz) inverts the first opamps -10v output to produce +10v peak. Now connect the piezo between the 2 opamp outputs.

Driving the first opamp with +-1v peak, will produce +- 10v peak from each opamp, and the complementary drive produces +-20 volts peak, or 40v peakpeak.

Now about an opamp to fairly accurately produce 10 volts at 4.25MHz: you will need a slewrate of 10v * 4.25 * 2 * PI === 240 volts/uS slewrate.

Answer (score 1):

If that's for a single pulse, you can use off-the-shelf components. As a pulser, you could use:

- NMT0572SC for high voltage generation from 5V
- TC6320TG for pulse production (you still need to supply it with High Voltage), using a MD1213 for control
- Protect the rest of the design with a MD0100

And you have yourself a nice [pulser board](https://github.com/kelu124/echomods/tree/master/retired/alt.tbo)!